# Check return value when parsing json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, return-value

I'm a beginner in ajax and json so I'm sorry if this question is a bit stupid. I'm retrieving the data(city id and name) and put them in an array then use json_encode. Then I call the getCities function but I'm not sure if I'm getting the correct cities. I tried using document.write but there's no output. How can I know if I'm getting the correct ones? Thank you for your help.

Here's the getCities.php:

```
$json = array();
$query = "SELECT cityID, cityName FROM city";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $coord = array('id' => $row['cityID'],'city' => $row['cityName']);
    array_push($json, $coord);
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
```

And here's the javascript part:

```
function getCities(){
        var string = $.ajax ({
                        url: "getCities.php",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).responseText;
        return JSON.parse(string);          
    }

    $(document).ready(function (){ 
        var city = getCities();
        while (city.length > 0) {
            document.write(city.pop + "<br/>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways to do this.  First of all I use Google Chrome (or Firefox) to facilitate testing.  Look at the docs and you will see that your $.ajax call will also accept a success function.  You could put it in the ajax call under dataType like this:

```
  var string = $.ajax ({
                        url: "getCities.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
      string.done();
```

Notice how I changed the end of the ajax call.  It is now saying, when this call is done, call the success function.  You can also put an error function in the ajax call if you want to have something print out in case of an error.  The success function will then be called when the data returns.  It will print in the console of your Chrome debugger.  Google that term to find out how to show it, super easy stuff.  You can also put a break point on the console.log function call (Google how to do that also) and you will be able to inspect the object that is returning from your ajax call.

Also, the console.log will not work in IE as far as I know.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCities(callback){
        var string = $.ajax ({
                        url: "getCities.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:callback
                   });       
    }

    $(document).ready(function (){ 
        getCities(function(data){
             console.log(data);
             var city = JSON.parse(data);
             if (city.length > 0) {
                document.write(city.pop + "<br/>");
             }
        });
    });
```

Ajax is asyn, you cannot use `var city = getCities();`. Because when you call that, ajax response has not arrived yet. You need to pass in a callback function, and when ajax response has arrived, call that function to get the response.